# "Cannot load such file" error during rake test in CircleCI after upgrading to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, upgrade, circleci

The 'bundle exec rake test' completes successfully locally, but when run on CircleCI it fails at the end, AFTER all the tests pass.  O.o

I just upgraded from rails 4.2.6 to Rails 5, was fine before this.  Something is looking for a test folder which I don't even have, there's a spec folder because I use rspec.

```
    Finished in 28.48 seconds (files took 3.67 seconds to load)
    329 examples, 0 failures

    Coverage report generated for RSpec to /tmp/circle-artifacts.PrVAaqN/coverage. 1425 / 1477 LOC (96.48%) covered.
    rake aborted!
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/ubuntu/app_name/test
    /home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in `block in require_files'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `require_files'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:62:in `rake_run'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/app_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: So I pulled it onto my other machine and gem installed, and getting the same thing locally on this machine now.  So there's something I must have done on the original machine that no others have.  Gem issue maybe?

Comment: Fails at "Execute test", but it already executed spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a conflict with rake task naming.  First of all, we're not supposed to use rake anymore even though it works, it has changed to the rails command.  The default rake/rails tasks of 'test' seemed to be messing everything up.  When I changed the task name to rspec it fixed everything.  It will do for now.